# Bearing from one coordinate to another

Tags: java, geolocation, bearing

I implemented the "bearing" formula from http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html. But it seems highly inaccurate - I suspect some mistakes in my implementation. Could you help me with finding it? My code is below:

```
protected static double bearing(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2){

double longDiff= lon2-lon1;
double y = Math.sin(longDiff)*Math.cos(lat2);
double x = Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2)*Math.cos(longDiff);

return Math.toDegrees((Math.atan2(y, x))+360)%360;
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You just have your parentheses `()` in the wrong place.

You are adding degrees to a value in radians, which won't work. `toDegrees()` will do the conversion from radians to degrees for you, *then* you do the normalisation once you have a value in degrees.

You have:

```
 Math.toDegrees( (Math.atan2(y, x))+360 ) % 360;
```

But you need:

```
( Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x)) + 360 ) % 360;
```

Remember also that all inputs to `Math.sin()`, `Math.cos()` and all the other trigonometric functions must be in radians. If your inputs are degrees you'll need to convert them using `Math.toRadians()` first.

Comment: Right! But still input params are
ProcJobLocation.bearing(53.944592, 27.595215, 55.745752, 37.630768);
and output is 359.11592632310266.
Still there is some mistake.

Comment: Your inputs seem to be in degrees. You need to convert them to radians using `Math.toRadians()`, otherwise `Math.sin()`, `Math.cos()` etc will give wrong results.

Answer (score 60):

Here is the final code:

```
protected static double bearing(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2){
  double longitude1 = lon1;
  double longitude2 = lon2;
  double latitude1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
  double latitude2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);
  double longDiff= Math.toRadians(longitude2-longitude1);
  double y= Math.sin(longDiff)*Math.cos(latitude2);
  double x=Math.cos(latitude1)*Math.sin(latitude2)-Math.sin(latitude1)*Math.cos(latitude2)*Math.cos(longDiff);

  return (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x))+360)%360;
}
```

Comment: where lat1, lon1, lat2 and lon2 are in radians???! Probably not. so why do you rename longitude1 and longitude2 ??

Answer (score 11):

> Bearing from one coordinate to another And Find North,East,south,weast :)[image]

```
     public class FindBearing {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println(" Your Result >>> "+FindBearing.bearing(19.2859590, 73.4966430, 19.2861020, 73.4988090));    
            }   
            protected static String bearing(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2){
          double longitude1 = lon1;
          double longitude2 = lon2;
          double latitude1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
          double latitude2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);
          double longDiff= Math.toRadians(longitude2-longitude1);
          double y= Math.sin(longDiff)*Math.cos(latitude2);
          double x=Math.cos(latitude1)*Math.sin(latitude2)-Math.sin(latitude1)*Math.cos(latitude2)*Math.cos(longDiff);
          double resultDegree= (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x))+360)%360;
          String coordNames[] = {"N","NNE", "NE","ENE","E", "ESE","SE","SSE", "S","SSW", "SW","WSW", "W","WNW", "NW","NNW", "N"};
          double directionid = Math.round(resultDegree / 22.5); 
          // no of array contain 360/16=22.5
          if (directionid < 0) {
              directionid = directionid + 16;
               //no. of contains in array
          }
          String compasLoc=coordNames[(int) directionid];

          return resultDegree+" "+compasLoc;
        }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

A little bit cleaned up version of [@IvanT answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9462757/746347):

```
public static double bearingInRadians(LatLng src, LatLng dst) {
    double srcLat = Math.toRadians(src.getLatitude());
    double dstLat = Math.toRadians(dst.getLatitude());
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(dst.getLongitude() - src.getLongitude());

    return Math.atan2(Math.sin(dLng) * Math.cos(dstLat),
            Math.cos(srcLat) * Math.sin(dstLat) - 
              Math.sin(srcLat) * Math.cos(dstLat) * Math.cos(dLng));
}

public static double bearingInDegrees(LatLng src, LatLng dst) {
    return Math.toDegrees((bearingInRadians(src, dst) + Math.PI) % Math.PI);
}
```

Where `LatLng` is:

```
public final class LatLng {
    private final double latitude;
    private final double longitude;

    public LatLng(double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
}
```