# ccpSub implementation for getting angle of 2 coordinates

Tags: ios, math, cocos2d-iphone, coordinates, angle

I an trying to figure out how ccpSub is implemented. Can someone point out the code for this ?

Basically, I came across this solution for getting the angle between 2 coordinates but its using cocos2d. I dont want the hassle of downloading the whole library just for this one function.
[Get angle from 2 positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064630/get-angle-from-2-positions)

Unfortunately, I am a bit lost as to how ccpSub is implemented in xcode ? Hope someone could guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: Whats wrong with the posted answers on the question you linked to which don't use cocos2d?

Comment: then look it up on github: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/develop-v2/cocos2d/Support/CGPointExtension.m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static inline CGPoint
ccpSub(const CGPoint v1, const CGPoint v2)
{
    return ccp(v1.x - v2.x, v1.y - v2.y);
}
```