# Player doesn't rotate towards mouse Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, rotation, trigonometry

Im trying to get my player sprite to rotate towards my mouse clicks. My player barely even moves and it prints out numbers in the decimals, such as "0.000991", What am i doing wrong?

```
    CGPoint endPoint = touchLocation;
    CGPoint startPoint = _plane.position;
    CGFloat angleVal =  atan2(endPoint.x -startPoint.x ,  endPoint.y- startPoint.y );
    CGFloat angle = angleVal* M_PI / 180;
    SKAction *planeAction = [SKAction rotateToAngle: angle duration:1];
    [_plane runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[planeAction]]];
    NSLog(@"%f",angle);
```

Comment: angleVal is already in radians, right? so why devide it by 180?

Answer (score 0):

`atan2` returns an angle in radians. You then try to convert it to radians, which ruins the value. `rotateToAngle:duration:` expects radians.

So, remove the `* M_PI / 180` calculation and use `angleVal` directly.

Comment: Yeah.  When you see small values like that you are usually looking at radians.

Comment: okay sweet, i got rid of that and I'm using angleVal directly, i also needed to multiply angleVal by -1 because it was going to the opposite side that i clicked. it is still extremely inaccurate and only works within the top 180 degrees.

Comment: @user3483259: Note that `atan2(y, x)` takes the y-component as the first argument.

Comment: You might want to take a look over some other answers for that, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064630/get-angle-from-2-positions

Comment: okay i switched around the X and Y for my atan2 argument and now it only works on the right side of my object and is still extremely inaccurate.

Comment: @wain i have looked at that post before, it uses methods from Cocos2D where i am using sprite kit here.

Comment: I didn't see any Cocos2d specific methods / functions when I scanned through it. There are other questions on the same topic too.