# Rotate a view from its origin towards another view

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, transform

I am trying to rotate a view towards another views center point(Remember not around, its towards).

Assume I have 2 views placed like this

[image]

Now I want to rotate the topview to point the bottom view like this

[image]

so this what I did

- Change the top views anchor point to its origin. so that it can rotate and point its edge to the bottom view
- Calculated the angle between the first views origin point and the bottom views center
- And applied the calculated transform to the top view.

  Below the code I am using

  ```
  let rect = CGRect(x: 70, y: 200, width: 300, height: 100)
  let rectView = UIView(frame: rect)
  rectView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor;
  rectView.layer.borderWidth = 2;

  let endView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 250, y: 450, width: 70, height: 70))
  endView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor;
  endView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
  let end = endView.center;

  self.view.addSubview(endView)
  self.view.addSubview(rectView!)
  rectView.setAnchorPoint(CGPoint.zero)

  let angle = rectView.bounds.origin.angle(to: end);
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {
      rectView.transform = rectView.transform.rotated(by: angle)
  }
  ```

I am using this extension from [Get angle from 2 positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064630/get-angle-from-2-positions) to calculate the angle between 2 points

```
extension CGPoint {
  func angle(to comparisonPoint: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
    let originX = comparisonPoint.x - self.x
    let originY = comparisonPoint.y - self.y
    let bearingRadians = atan2f(Float(originY), Float(originX))
    var bearingDegrees = CGFloat(bearingRadians).degrees
    while bearingDegrees < 0 {
        bearingDegrees += 360
    }
    return bearingDegrees
  }
}

extension CGFloat {
    var degrees: CGFloat {
        return self * CGFloat(180.0 / M_PI)
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func setAnchorPoint(_ point: CGPoint) {
        var newPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width * point.x, y: bounds.size.height * point.y)
        var oldPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width * layer.anchorPoint.x, y: bounds.size.height * layer.anchorPoint.y);

        newPoint = newPoint.applying(transform)
        oldPoint = oldPoint.applying(transform)

        var position = layer.position

        position.x -= oldPoint.x
        position.x += newPoint.x

        position.y -= oldPoint.y
        position.y += newPoint.y

        layer.position = position
        layer.anchorPoint = point
    }
}
```

But this isn't working as expected, the rotation is way off. Check the below screen capture of the issue

[image]

I assume this issue is related to how the angle is calculated, but I could't figure out what?

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `UIView` doesn't have a `setAnchorPoint` method? How is that defined?

Comment: @vacawama, its an extension to uiview. I have added it now. please check the edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Angles need to be in radians**

The rotation angle needs to be specified in radians:

Change:

```
rectView.transform = rectView.transform.rotated(by: angle)
```

to:

```
rectView.transform = rectView.transform.rotated(by: angle / 180.0 * .pi)
```

or change your `angle(to:)` method to return radians instead of degrees.

---

**Use `frame` instead of `bounds`**

Also, you need to use the `frame` of your `rectView` when computing the angle.  The `bounds` of a view is its internal coordinate space, which means its origin is always `(0, 0)`.  You want the `frame` which is the coordinates of the view in its parent's coordinate system.

Change:

```
let angle = rectView.bounds.origin.angle(to: end)
```

to:

```
let angle = rectView.frame.origin.angle(to: end)
```

---

**Note:**  Because your `anchorPoint` is the corner of `rectView`, this will point the top edge of `rectView` to the center of `endView`.  One way to fix that would be to change your `anchorPoint` to the center of the left edge of `rectView` and then use that point to compute your `angle`.

Comment: Great!  Thanks for updating your question.