# Set css rotation to point an element towards a point

Tags: jquery, css, css-transforms

I am trying to rotate a div towards a point using css 3 transform rotate function.

I got up to this point: [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ramesh64/7ae3kxam/35/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var scw,sch,scx,scy;
    calcCenter();
    $(window).resize(function() {         
        calcCenter();
    });
    function calcCenter(){
      sch = $(window).height(); 
      scw = $(window).width(); 
      scx = scw/2;
      scy = sch/2;
        $(".circle").remove();
      var circle = $("<span></span>").addClass('circle').text('.');
      circle.css('top',scy-50+"px");
      circle.css('left',scx-50+"px");
    $(document.body).append(circle);
    }
    function calcAngle(p1,p2){

        var angle = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
        return angle;
    }



    $(document).click(function(e){  
        var box = $("<span></span>").addClass('box');
        var x = e.pageX,y=e.pageY; 
        box.css('top',y+"px");
        box.css('left',x+"px"); 

        $(document.body).append(box);
        var angle = calcAngle({x:x,y:y},{x:scx,y:scy});

        box.css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+(90+angle)*-1+'deg)');        

        box.draggable({
                drag: function(e) {
                        var box = $(this);
                        var x = e.pageX,y=e.pageY; 
                        box.css('top',y+"px");
                        box.css('left',x+"px");
                        var angle = calcAngle({x:x,y:y},{x:scx,y:scy});

                        box.css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+(90+angle)*-1+'deg)');


                        }
                      });
    });

    var sunAngle = 1;
    setInterval(function(){
        var sun = $("span.circle")[0];
        $(sun).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+sunAngle+'deg)');
        sunAngle = (sunAngle+1) %360;           
    },100);
});
```

I googled "lookat" function, and found something like lookat matrix only.

Comment: For starters its confusing that the default orientation of the leaves is south-west. Nonetheless, I will attempt to fix your math. Nice fiddle btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the center of your circle is not being calculated correctly. Your circle is 120px wide and high, but you "center" it by setting its top and left to `scy - 50`, where you should have used `scy - 60` (half of 120px is 60px). Or even better, also calculate half circle width and height dynamically and subtract that, in case you change your mind and make it a different size again.

I just did it statically:

```
circle.css('top',scy-60+"px");
circle.css('left',scx-60+"px");
```

Second, you want to calculate the angle the `.box` elements needs to rotate around its center, but you use its top and left positions to do so. That's incorrect.

Again, dynamic would be better, but let's do it static for now:

```
var angle = calcAngle({x:x + 32,y:y + 32},{x:scx,y:scy});
```

Then I'm not sure what you're doing with `atan2() * 180 / Math.PI`, since `atan2` returns rads and you want degrees I double checked how to calculate between the two. Turns out it's not as simple as you thought. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311049/how-to-map-atan2-to-degrees-0-360).

So I added a function:

```
function radToDegree(rad) {
    return (rad > 0 ? rad : (2*Math.PI + rad)) * 360 / (2*Math.PI)
}
```

And implemented it before returning the angle:

```
function calcAngle(p1,p2){      
    var angle = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x);
    return radToDegree(angle);
}
```

Now, degrees start from the top, meaning if the angle is 0 degrees it will point upwards whereas you need it to point to the right due to the way your calculations are set up. So you added `+ 90` to your final rotate calculations.

That would have been fine if your point started upwards, but it doesn't. It starts from the bottom left, which is another 135 degrees. Add those up, and you get a 225 degree difference. So:

```
box.css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+(angle+225)+'deg)');
```

And voila, your script works: http://jsfiddle.net/7ae3kxam/42/

edit: also works for dragging now

Comment: works brilliant for the initial add, but dragging doesnt - have mostly fixed that in the `drag` method - http://jsfiddle.net/7ae3kxam/40/ it just does weird stuff at  270deg

Comment: And just to start off on what your next step will probably be, some attempt at rotating them on window resize http://jsfiddle.net/7ae3kxam/41/ ... I should probably start doing some work now.

Comment: Oops, thanks Rhumborl. Updated the fiddle for dragging.