# Transform mouse svg to polar plot coordinates using d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I [created](http://jsfiddle.net/crbmba60/) a polar plot using d3 similar [to this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4583749).

[image: Polar plot]

How can I transform the svg coordinates to polar coordinates?

```js
var svgPolar = d3.select("#polar")
    .append("svg")
    .on("mousemove", function(){$("#coords").text(d3.mouse(this));})
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
```

I already have the x and y coordinates of the mouse movement on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crbmba60/).
Thanks.

**Edit**

I adjusted it to my needs. But it looks a little ugly to distinguish the azimuth angle.

```
.on("mousemove", function(){
    var coords = d3.mouse(this);
    var adjusted_x = coords[0] - ( width / 2 );
    var adjusted_y = coords[1] - ( height / 2 );
    var d = Math.sqrt( ( adjusted_x * adjusted_x ) + ( adjusted_y * adjusted_y ) );
    var degrees_elevation = (( 1 - d/radius ) * 90).toFixed(2)
    var angle_azimuth = Math.atan2( adjusted_y, adjusted_x );
    var degrees_azimuth = ( angle_azimuth + ( Math.PI/2 ) ) * ( 180 / ( Math.PI ) );
    var degrees_azimuth_fixed = (degrees_azimuth > 0 ? degrees_azimuth : (degrees_azimuth+360)).toFixed(2);
    if(degrees_elevation >= 0)
        $("#coords").text(degrees_azimuth_fixed + " " + degrees_elevation);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/crbmba60/2/

Answer (score 2):

This is actually reasonably straightforward once you convert your cartesian coordinates to reference the center of the plot area instead of the upper left corner.

```
var coords = d3.mouse(this);    
var adjusted_x = coords[0] - ( width / 2 );
var adjusted_y = coords[1] - ( height / 2 );
```

Once you have that, you can get the distance from the center using the Pythagorean theorem

```
var d = Math.sqrt( ( adjusted_x * adjusted_x ) + ( adjusted_y * adjusted_y ) );
```

and your angle using atan2

```
var angle = Math.atan2( adjusted_y, adjusted_x );
```

The one additional point of complexity is that atan2 will give you an angle where 0 degrees (or 2 pi radians) corresponds with an easterly direction.  To convert the angle in radians to the number of degrees corresponding to a cardinal direction, you will need to add Math.PI / 2 to the angle that atan2 gives you.  For instance,

```
var angle_in_degrees = ( Math.atan2( adjusted_y, adjusted_x ) + ( Math.PI / 2 ) ) * ( 360 / ( Math.PI * 2 ) );
```

Those should be the basic ingredients you need to perform any positioning math based on mouse coordinates.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. It brought me to a solution. Could you may look into my solution if we could ease the code a little? For atan2  adjustion I looked into [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311049/how-to-map-atan2-to-degrees-0-360). But I will accept your answer anyway.