# swift calculating degree of joystick rotation

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm working on a spritekit game using swift and I implemented a joystick using [this](https://github.com/MitrophD/Swift-SpriteKit-Analog-Stick) library. I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to calculate the degree of the rotation. the library gives you this information when you move the joystick around

```
joystick.trackingHandler = { jData in
  // something...
  // jData contains angular && velocity (jData.angular, jData.velocity)
}
```

I don't need to rotate the player since the game is a 4 directional jrpg style, so i'll just be triggering movement based on a range of degrees.

does anybody have any useful articles or information on turning the velocity returned into a degree?

I've seen people using `atan2` but it seems to only accept Double's and the velody returned is of type CGPoint.

Comment: Access the `x` and `y` members of `CGPoint` to get `CGFloat`s that you can use with `atan2`

Comment: so i tried that, `atan2(data.velocity.x, data.velocity.y)`, but it gives me the same numbers when i print as `data.velocity`. any ideas why?

Comment: to be clear, the velocity goes from 0 to 3, and -3 to 0 rotating clockwise.

Comment: To be fair, I haven't looked at this framework. Shouldn't you be dealing with the position (that's all you care about, no?) of the joystick, not its velocity?

Comment: hey, if i knew i wouldn't be posting here :D

Comment: The docs for that library are very sparse when it comes to using it! But it seems to me that `angular` is the number you are after.

Comment: i agree, angular is looking like what i need, but how can i convert those numbers into something useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `angular` value in `jData` contains the angle in radians.

To convert, use the following code for values between -180 and +180:

```
let degrees = jData.angular * 360 / (2 * M_PI)
```

and this for values between 0 and +360:

```
var radians = jData.angular
radians = radians > 0 ? radians : (2 * M_PI + radians)
let degrees = radians * 360 / (2 * M_PI)
```

adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1311134/968577

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you man! coming from the web to iOS has made me realize how bad at math i am :O