# how to map atan2() to only positive radian?

Tags: math, atan2

`atan2(y, x)` has that discontinuity at PI (180°) where it switches to -PI..0 (-180°..0°) going clockwise.

if i apply the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311049/how-to-map-atan2-to-degrees-0-360)

```
// rust
(y.atan2(x).to_degrees() + 360.0) % 360.0
```

doesn't quite work with radians

```
(y.atan2(x) + PI*2.0) % PI*2.0 // doesn't give the right output most of the times
```

i am probably doing it wrong, cause i am not good at math

so what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the modulo operator and multiplication have the same precedence, and are left-associative, so your last expression is equivalent to

```
((y.atan2(x) + PI*2.0) % PI) * 2.0
```

If you put parentheses around the second `PI*2.0`, it should work:

```
(y.atan2(x) + PI*2.0) % (PI*2.0)
```

Comment: yep... it was a typo indeed